# Apple rejecting app for using Clinical Health Records API, react-native-health

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, healthkit

I am developing an app using the react-native-health package. I'm keep getting the below messages from Apple

Furthermore, we continue to find that your app uses the Clinical Health Records API but your app does not appear to include any primary features that require the Clinical Health Records API.

To resolve this issue, please remove the Clinical Health Records API from your app, as well as any references to this app’s interactivity with Clinical Health Records from your app or its metadata.

I have followed the instructions that Apple has provided, but I am still not able to resolve the issue. I am not sure what else I can do to fix this.

I would appreciate any help that you can provide.

Comment: You should check the packages you have included. Probably one of them is referencing the clinical heath records framework

Comment: I did, but there's nothing about it!

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/agencyenterprise/react-native-health/issues/320.